# How do I remove the exit code part of the powerline prompt

Tags: powerline

I have started to use Powerline for my terminal prompt and while I have gotten it all working I am not sure how to configure the segments. I have tried messing around with the files in the `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/powerline` directory but nothing seems to be changing. I specifically want to remove the exit code extension so any help on that would be great.

Yes I have tried reading the docs but I couldn't understand what file to edit and where and what to change.

(I want to remove the red 1 segment shown here)

[image: An image of what is happening]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now discovered my issue. In order to reload the config you need to put the following in the terminal. I also moved my config files to `~/.config/powerline`

`powerline-daemon --replace`